# How to hide overflow x in responsive site

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I have a problem. When I go to responsive mode, the overflow x are enabled and I don't know how to disable it.
I try to @media disable overflow but its not work

Comment: Can you provide HTML and CSS?

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden`?

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

If this doesn't work, there may be other CSS rules that are overriding your code.

Comment: No this work . Do you think the problem is in css?

Comment: maybe yeah if  can provide me with the css code , it will be better , but i didnt understand , did my solution work or no ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the overflow-hidden to the div class without having it in the CSS file. Here is some documentation.

[Overflow Utility - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/overflow/)